# Expanding preview not displaying in line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to make a custom expanding preview [like this](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/). But in my case when I click on a circular div to expand for the preview, it displays at the end of the page, instead of displaying it on line (below the circular div). Please help me with this.

Do I need to use append function of JavaScript to get it done?

Please help me with this issue, I am unable to find the solution to this.

`Link for my code` - [link](https://jsfiddle.net/nayyarmannu/p5085mr0/1/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=p5085mr0).

Thank You

Comment: You should move the dynamic content into the same div as the parent div for the circle.

Comment: @ravb79 u mean to say that the tab div should be inside the circular div?

Comment: I think that should do the trick, yes.

Comment: @ravb79 but in that approach, i am facing a problem. When i click on the circular div, the circular div(s) to its right shifts down to display the tab.

Comment: That should only happen when the elements in the parent div are floated or displayed inline. If both elements (circle and tab) are set to block, the second div (tab) should be forced underneath the first div.

Comment: @ravb79 when I am trying to do that, all the circular div is coming in a new row.